# Отменяет ли снятие голоса за закрытие попадание в очередь?

Tags: поддержка, закрытие-вопросов, очередь-проверок

Если я сначала проголосовал за закрытие [вопроса](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496859/178988) как дубликата, а потом передумал и отменил этот голос (до появления других голосов),то вопрос всё равно пройдёт через соответствующую очередь, или будет из неё исключён?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, что отменяет, по крайней мере если никто из проверяющих не успел проголосовать за закрытие. Возможно также, что вопрос просто не успел попасть в очередь (т.е. есть задержка между первым голосом за закрытие и очередью). Смотрим:

В 07:20:31 вы подумали о том, чтобы отозвать голос. В 07:21:17, видимо, отозвали.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос побывал только в очереди первых сообщений.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/64053

> **Проверка завершена 2 часа назад:**
>   VenZell проверил данный объект 2 часа назад: **Просмотрено**

Comment: О, всё-таки модераторская шкала отличается от обычной :)

Comment: А почему очищено Духом?

Comment: @Qwertiy видимо, он приходит чтобы отменить ваш голос )